# Error creating shader from memory

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl

Because of `d3dcompiler*.dll` becomes undesireable, I'm trying to exclude dependencies to it from my app. And there is something wrong with my new Compiled Shader Object (.cso) file loading code.

```
ifstream fstream;  
fstream.open (vsfile);
if(fstream.fail())
    return false;

fstream.seekg( 0, ios::end );  
size_t size = size_t(fstream.tellg());  
char* data = new char[size];

fstream.seekg(0, ios::beg);  
fstream.read( data, size);  
fstream.close();  

XTRACE2(pDevice->CreateVertexShader(&data, size, 0, &m_pVertexShader))
```

The problem: `CreateVertexShader()` returning `E_INVALIDARG` error.

Old code with `D3DReadFileToBlob()` works fine. Blob returns buffer of the same size that is my `char*` or `std::vector<char>` and its equal to `.cso` file size. 
I know, there are new Windows 8 examples on MSDN, but they use some new Metro stuff. I want to do It with plain C++.

`XTRACE2` is just DirectX error checking macro.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `data` the compiled shader? Otherwise, you have to compile it first.

Comment: Yes, it is Compiled Shader Object created by VS2012 (AFAIK it uses fxc.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Error was caused by reading binary in text mode. Works as intended if add binary flag to read function. Something like that:

```
            std::ifstream fstream;  
            fstream.open (filename,  std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
            if(fstream.fail())
                return false;

            fstream.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );  
            size_t size = size_t(fstream.tellg());  
            data.resize(size);  
            fstream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);  
            fstream.read( &data[0], size);  
            fstream.close();
```

Shame on me =\